# My Ubuntu pc hangs randomly after boot with horizontal lines

Tags: 18.04

My Ubuntu desktop hangs randomly  after boot (after logging in Ubuntu) with horizontal lines like these:

[Horizontal lines sample (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKdvl.jpg)

OS - ubuntu 18.04

Edit:. Added hardware details:

Processor : Intel i3

Ram 16 GB

(I have been running Ubuntu on this pc for over a year now, but this problem arose a few days back)
Can anyone please help?

Edit 1:
lshw output:

```
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 15GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1665MHz
          capacity: 3400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:f0434000-f0437fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:26 memory:f0420000-f042ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f0440000-f044000f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 05
             serial: d0:50:99:29:62:71
             size: 100Mbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.29.156 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:28 memory:f0400000-f041ffff memory:f043d000-f043dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f043c000-f043c3ff
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:f0430000-f0433fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:dfa00000-dfbfffff ioport:dfc00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: d5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
                vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f043b000-f043b3ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: B85 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:27 ioport:f0d0(size=8) ioport:f0c0(size=4) ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f043a000-f043a7ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f0439000-f04390ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: iHAS124   E
             vendor: ATAPI
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 4L07
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Edit 2: output of lswh -C memory :

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P2.10
       date: 07/03/2014
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: CPU Internal L1
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:0
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: CPU Internal L2
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:1
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: e
       slot: CPU Internal L3
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: f
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 14731022
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 14722443
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 2
          serial: 14730622
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 3
          serial: 14010719
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

Edit 3 : Memtest86 Results(after BIOS update):

```
Summary
Report Date     2020-06-09 01:28:27
Generated by    MemTest86 V8.4 Free (64-bit)
Result  PASS
System Information
EFI Specifications  2.31
System  
Manufacturer    To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product Name    To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Version     To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Serial Number   To Be Filled By O.E.M.
BIOS    
Vendor  American Megatrends Inc.
Version     P2.50
Release Date    12/11/2015
Baseboard   
Manufacturer    ASRock
Product Name    B85M Pro4
Version     
Serial Number   E80-45025001224
CPU Type    Intel Core i3-4130 @ 3.40GHz
CPU Clock   3392 MHz
# Logical Processors    4 (2 enabled for testing)
L1 Cache    4 x 64K (175576 MB/s)
L2 Cache    4 x 256K (53978 MB/s)
L3 Cache    3072K (40268 MB/s)
Memory  16050M (18165 MB/s)
DIMM Slot #0    4GB DDR3 PC3-12800
    Samsung / M378B5173QH0-CK0 / 95490AE5
    11-11-11-28 / 1600 MHz / 1.5V
DIMM Slot #1    4GB DDR3 PC3-12800
    Samsung / M378B5173QH0-CK0 / 9548F12B
    11-11-11-28 / 1600 MHz / 1.5V
DIMM Slot #2    4GB DDR3 PC3-12800
    Samsung / M378B5173QH0-CK0 / 954906E4
    11-11-11-28 / 1600 MHz / 1.5V
DIMM Slot #3    4GB DDR3 PC3-12800
    Samsung / M378B5173QH0-CK0 / 920107C4
    11-11-11-28 / 1600 MHz / 1.5V
Result summary
Test Start Time 2020-06-08 15:58:46
Elapsed Time    4:08:12
Memory Range Tested     0x0 - 41E600000 (16870MB)
CPU Selection Mode  Parallel (All CPUs)
ECC Polling     Enabled
# Tests Passed  48/48 (100%)
Test    # Tests Passed  Errors
Test 0 [Address test, walking ones, 1 CPU]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 1 [Address test, own address, 1 CPU]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 2 [Address test, own address]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 3 [Moving inversions, ones & zeroes]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 4 [Moving inversions, 8-bit pattern]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 5 [Moving inversions, random pattern]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 6 [Block move, 64-byte blocks]     4/4 (100%)  0
Test 7 [Moving inversions, 32-bit pattern]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 8 [Random number sequence]     4/4 (100%)  0
Test 9 [Modulo 20, ones & zeros]    4/4 (100%)  0
Test 10 [Bit fade test, 2 patterns, 1 CPU]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 13 [Hammer test]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 13 [Hammer test] Warning
Note: Your RAM may be vulnerable to high frequency row hammer bit flips. However the conditions needed to induce these errors occur only very rarely in normal PC usage, and so this should not be of concern to most users.
Certification
This document certifies that the Tests described above have been carried out by a suitably qualified technician on the System described above.
```

Comment: Be more precise. At what stage does it happen after startup? After or before logging in? After the OEM screen but before the login screen is shown? Also provide details on your hardware.

Comment: @vanadium It freezes after I have logged in Ubuntu. And it is completely random anywhere between 5 minutes to 30 minutes of booting. I have edited the question for hardware details

Comment: Details are quite limited. Use `lshw -html > hardware.html` and in the resulting html file, copy the parts related to your graphics card and display.  See whether it is a user configuration issue by creating a new account and seeing if the issue also occurs while logged in there. You did some changes to the system recently? Could be a hardware failure, though. Have a look at the kernel logs.

Comment: @vanadium added the lage output to the question. I changed nothing in user configuration recently. I will check new user account suggestion also and post if I see any difference. How do I see kernel logs?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`, and then go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the output of lshw-C memory to the question. And tried to do memtest86. It got stuck after a point I am attaching image here : Memtest86 result https://imgur.com/gallery/NIhbYKN

Comment: @AviD1511 Before I tell you how to troubleshoot bad RAM, let's check your BIOS, as yours is very old. What model AMI motherboard do you have?

Comment: @heynnema my MB is ASRock - B85M Pro4. and I just took out one DIMM out of the slot just to check which one of the DIMM has gone bad. PC is running fine for the time being. (dont know if it is random as before or because of pulling bad ram dimm)

Comment: @AviD1511 **That's the wrong way to troubleshoot memory**. Re-insert the RAM stick, follow my instructions, do the BIOS FIRST, then follow the memory troubleshooting instructions EXACTLY.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for the delay it takes a long time to complete the memtest. I have updates the question and also commented to the answer. Thanks and Good morning.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the answer with memtest result. Apparently the ram is ok, but the main problem of  freezing of Ubuntu with horizontal lines still exists. Kindly help

Comment: @AviD1511 You have a desktop computer, yes? Are you using built-in Intel video card, or do you have a Nvidia card, or some other video card? Is that an external LCD monitor?

Comment: @heynnema yes it is a desktop computer, and there is no nvidia card, It is using built in intel card. Yes it is an external lcd monitor.

Comment: @heynnema No I don't, I could have brought one from office but my city is under lockdown due to pandemic.

Comment: @heynnema  No this is the only pc I have access to these days.

Comment: @AviD1511 If the BIOS has been updated, and memtest runs ok now, then I think that you must have some other hardware problem with your computer. You could review /var/log/syslog for clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

You have BIOS version P2.10, dated 07/03/2014.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 2.50, dated 12/22/2015, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/b85m%20pro4/#BIOS).

After updating the BIOS, rerun `memtest`.

**Note**: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

---

**Memory**

`Memtest` memory test has failed. Here's how to troubleshoot which RAM stick(s) might be defective.

Note in `sudo lshw -C memory` there are these memory slots. They may or may not be similarly marked on the motherboard.

First matched pair...

```
ChannelA-DIMM0
ChannelB-DIMM0
```

Second matched pair...

```
ChannelA-DIMM1
ChannelB-DIMM1
```

Repeat the following five steps every time you add/remove RAM sticks...

- Remove AC power from the computer
- Press and hold the power ON button until the fans stop spinning
- Ground yourself to earth ground
- Remove the second matched pair of RAM sticks
- Reconnect AC power

Then continue...

- Boot computer and verify that the first matched pair of RAM sticks are in the correct slots, as per `sudo lshw -C memory`. If not, move them until they are.
- Rerun `memtest`
- If `memtest` passes 4/4 tests, then those two RAM sticks are good
- If `memtest` fails, then one/both of the RAM sticks are bad
- Remove those RAM sticks, and insert the previously removed RAM sticks, INTO THE SAME SLOTS for the first matched pair
- Rerun `memtest`
- If `memtest` passes 4/4 tests, then those two RAM sticks are good
- If `memtest` fails, then one/both of the RAM sticks are bad

**Update #1:**

Updating the BIOS fixed the memory problem.

Comment: Thanks for such a lucid and detailed answer. I updated the BIOS to the latest version and rerun the memtest. The memtest passed. I have added the results of memtest to the question.